# Which hive-site.xml is used by Hive's CLI

Tags: linux, hive, command-line-interface

A test server contains a lot of `hive-site.xml` files.

I run Hive's CLI by `hive` command.

How to identify which `hive-site.xml` file is used by that Hive's CLI?

`HIVE_CONF_DIR` environment variable is not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute this

```
hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console -e '' 2>&1 | grep hive-site.xml
```

Demo

```
bash-4.1$ hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console -e '' 2>&1 | grep hive-site.xml
17/05/29 07:45:38 [main]: DEBUG common.LogUtils: Using hive-site.xml found on CLASSPATH at /etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml
bash-4.1$
```